# Flat file database for CD

Tags: database, sqlite, software-design, flat-file

I have a .csv file with about 5-8 columns and about 1mil. rows and I would like to have it stored in simple flat file database.

Overall this should be a standalone application (one file with *.exe, installable under Windows). The application would allow basic search on the 5-8 columns. There should be very simple `user interface`.

This application is to be written on CD and distributed to users so should be fairly simple to administer/use.

**Questions:**

1) Is there already some software that would allow me to build such a application?

2) If not which program would suit best to build such a application?

I would task a programmer to build such a application if I would have clue as to what program to use (finding programmer based on the best program you would recommend).

Again, very simple application, light weight with no additional unnecessary options, dependencies etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Visual Database (http://myvisualdatabase.com/)

from site:

> A simple development environment databases, without the help of
>   specialists and programming skills, you will create a Windows
>   application databases. It can be as simple telephone directory and
>   accounting system in your business.
>
> The result of your work will be a Windows application that does not
>   require installation and third-party components and the ability to
>   work directly from USB Flash drive.

This software uses sqlite.

Here you can find example, how to import csv file
http://myvisualdatabase.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=1448

also for import you can use SQLite Studio

Comment: This looks good but it may be a little bit more what I actually need. I just solved it with excel and VBA macros. Thank you.